# Stretch image on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I just came cross an impressive portfolio, which you can see here: https://kulbachny.com/

I was wondering, how did he achieve that 'stretched and blurred' effect when moving the cursor hover his image?

I can imagine it has to do with canvas and maybe Three.js/WebGL (not so sure)(?)

I'd love to achieve the same effect, but I guess that's not so simple..

If you know how to do it, could you please explain how something such this can be built? 
And if too long to explain, could you refer to good guides or technologies / libraries to study in order to be able to build this kind of animations?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what his own site is build with. But site's of his portofolio are made with TweenMax Javascript framework. You can look up yourself some TweenMax tutorials.